# Calculate distance and surface with mapbox api

Tags: javascript, mapbox

Is there a way to draw lines and polygons (with geojson) and calculate distance and polygon surface with the mapbox api or leaflet? 
I wish to have the same tools as in geojson.io with the extra ability to calculate line length and polygon surface.
For lines I will use the Leaflet method *distanceTo* but for the polygon surface I have no clue.

Comment: You'll need to be more detailed about what you're trying to accomplish, espec. re. "calculate ... polygon surface".

Comment: You mean polygon area, as in, say square metres? And do you mean conventional, horizontal (planar) area, and not surface area (which depends on terrain/relief)?

Comment: Correct I mean planar area

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lines and polygons can be drawn in Leaflet either by the user of the application with [Leaflet Draw](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/leaflet-draw/)

Or programmatically, with [geojson](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html) - or [other leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html) or [mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v1.6.2/) classes

For distances and length you might look into [Leaflet GeometryUtil](http://makinacorpus.github.io/Leaflet.GeometryUtil/)

And you can calculate the area of a polygon with [geojson-area](https://github.com/mapbox/geojson-area)